# How to find page rendering time(not page loading time) using javascript

Tags: javascript

I use below syntax to find page loading time but not sure how to identify page rendering time using javascript.

```
var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd- window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516665/how-can-i-monitor-the-rendering-time-in-a-browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I monitor the rendering time in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516665/how-can-i-monitor-the-rendering-time-in-a-browser)

Comment: var rendertime = window.performance.timing.domComplete-window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd

Comment: @Vibhu: Can u add this as your answer.

Comment: What do you call rendering time? There will be a lot of rendering during the page life.

Comment: @Kaiido: Render time is the time it takes to actually process downloaded Js, CSS, images and show their end-result to the visitor.

Comment: That's only the first rendering then, and it might not be easy to get a precise time for it with only WebAPIs... there is not really a paint event, the closest I can think of is transition-end, but you'll always have a delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rendertime = window.performance.timing.domComplete-window.performance.tim‌​ing.domContentLoaded‌​EventEnd
```

Comment: That's parsing time, not rendering time.

Comment: Well , as per this answer , both rendering and parsing almost occur simultaneously.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35966477/4589611

Comment: Well that might be true for the first one, but all subsequent renderings will have nothing to do with parsing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Overview_of_Events_and_Handlers and https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction (But it seems OP is only interested in this first rendering)